# How can i show some data on Pandas DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, data-visualization

I have scraped some updated day-by-day data (only numbers). **I want to show them in a good table (data frame)**. I don't know how to use Pandas. I am using python and the end result should look like a table with defined keys on it. Thanks

And here is my python code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/Austria/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text , 'html.parser')



#RECOVERD , DEATHS AND TOTAL CASES
Covid_Cases_Array = []
get_Covid_Cases = soup.find_all(class_ = 'maincounter-number')

for item in get_Covid_Cases:
  Covid_Cases_Array.append(item.text)
  print(item.text)

# Active ND CLOSED DATA
Covid_Active_Closed = []
get_Activ_Closed = soup.find_all(class_ = 'number-table-main')
for item in get_Activ_Closed:
  Covid_Active_Closed.append(item.text)
  print(item.text)
```

And the result of that code :

```
600,089 


9,997


563,256

26,836
573,253
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example how to get the data from the page to DataFrame:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/Austria/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

cases, deaths, recovered = soup.select(".maincounter-number")
active_cases, closed_cases = soup.select(".number-table-main")
active_cases_mild, active_cases_serious, _, _ = soup.select(".number-table")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Coronavirus Cases": [cases.get_text(strip=True)],
        "Deaths": [deaths.get_text(strip=True)],
        "Recovered": [recovered.get_text(strip=True)],
        "Currently infected": [active_cases.get_text(strip=True)],
        "Closed cases": [closed_cases.get_text(strip=True)],
        "Active cases (mild)": [active_cases_mild.get_text(strip=True)],
        "Active cases (serious)": [active_cases_serious.get_text(strip=True)],
    }
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Coronavirus Cases Deaths Recovered Currently infected Closed cases Active cases (mild) Active cases (serious)
0           600,089  9,997   563,256             26,836      573,253              26,279                    557
```